# Face and Eye Detection using OpenCV does not work correctly

Tags: java, opencv

I created a small OpenCV based library but the eye and face detection is off. I downloaded the haarcascade_eye.xml and haarcascade_profileface.xml directly from OpenCV's github, copy it to a temp folder and it works well.

Sadly the result is disgusting and incorrect. Two years ago when I did something similar the result with OpenCV was way better. I am basically using the base image and apply both classifiers using detectMultiScale. I do not scale the image and it has no effect whether or not I use the grayscale version or the colored one.

Looking at this (and the other test images), I would say this is a failing grade. So in the end I must miss something here and if OpenCV is a failure, what alternatives for todays face/eye/detection needs exist?

The OpenCV version is 4.5.1-2 (org.openpnp:opencv:4.5.1-2) but I manually loaded both xml classifier specs from github two days ago.

[image: Popular AI generated faces image with detected faces (red) and eyes (green)]

Popular AI generated faces image with detected faces (red) and eyes (green)

Comment: The good ones from github don't do us any good. Could you please post some images with their incorrectly detected eyes/faces to compare them with?

Comment: For eye detection, you can better use [Face landmark detection](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/d42/tutorial_face_landmark_detection_in_an_image.html).

Comment: @NomadMaker I have difficulties understanding your request. The image I provided shows you that the face areas are shifted, too big and incorrect. The eyes (green rectangles) include nostrils, hair and mouth corners. Quite bad if you ask me.

Comment: Turned out I had the profileface detector enabled. Than it makes sense. I will try to improve the eye detection as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For face detection I encourage you to use the DNN face detector of OpenCV. Less false positives that using Viola-Jones and very easy to use. Find in the next link a good comparison: https://learnopencv.com/face-detection-opencv-dlib-and-deep-learning-c-python/

Find below a rough idea how to call it in python. But very similar in C++:

Initialization:

```
print("  >> Loading DNN_TF_OCV model for face detection...")
modelFile = "models/opencv_face_detector_uint8.pb"
configFile = "models/opencv_face_detector.pbtxt"
detector = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow(modelFile, configFile)
```

Detection:

```
 def __detectFaceOpenCVDnnTF(self, frame):
        frameOpencv = frame.copy()
        frameHeight = frameOpencv.shape[0]
        frameWidth = frameOpencv.shape[1]
        blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frameOpencv, 1.0, (300, 300), [104, 117, 123], False, False)

        self.detector.setInput(blob)
        detections = self.detector.forward()
        bboxes = []
        for i in range(detections.shape[2]):
            confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]
            if confidence > self.conf_threshold:
                x1 = int(detections[0, 0, i, 3] * frameWidth)
                y1 = int(detections[0, 0, i, 4] * frameHeight)
                x2 = int(detections[0, 0, i, 5] * frameWidth)
                y2 = int(detections[0, 0, i, 6] * frameHeight)
                bboxes.append([x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1])

        return bboxes
```

For the eye detection, I suggest the same idea that @Quang Hoang suggested. Use face landmarks detection. The LBF implementation of OpenCV is very fast and easy to use. You can use also the ERT model from Dlib.

- https://learnopencv.com/facemark-facial-landmark-detection-using-opencv/
- https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/04/03/facial-landmarks-dlib-opencv-python/

Cheers

Comment: Looks way better I agree.